# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare parse_external_url()

Tags: php

i write a piece of  code in order to parse  URL in a web site given as input(i choose the web site : www.tunisie-web.org ) ,and determinate if there are external
my script php: crawl.php 's contents

```
       <?php 
         set_time_limit(10000); 
     include_once('../PHPCrawl_083/PHPCrawl_083/libs/PHPCrawler.class.php'); 

    class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler  
    {  
     function handleDocumentInfo(PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo $DocInfo)  
     { 
  // Just detect linebreak for output ("\n" in CLI-mode, otherwise "<br>"). 
   if (PHP_SAPI == "cli" ) $lb = "\n";
   else { 
   $lb = "<br/>";
   function parse_external_url( $url) {
   echo "0"."<br/>";
   // Abort if parameter URL is empty
   if( empty($url) ) {
    echo "l'url est vide"."<br/>";
}
echo "1"."<br/>";

     // Parse home URL and parameter URL
     $link_url = parse_url( $url );
      $home_url = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );     
       //$home_url = parse_url( home_url() );  // Works for WordPress

      // Decide on target
      if( $link_url['host'] == $home_url['host'] ) {
       // Is an internal link
       echo "<br/>";
      echo "2"."<br/>";
       }     
      else {
       // Is an external link
       // Print the URL and the HTTP-status-Code 
       echo "Page requested: ".$url." (".$url->http_status_code.")"."<br/>"; 

      // Print the refering URL 
       echo "Referer-page: ".$url->referer_url."<br/>";
       }
        echo "3";


        }
        parse_external_url( $DocInfo->url);
        echo "<br/>"; 
       flush(); 
         }
       } 
      } 
    $crawler = new MyCrawler(); 
    $crawler->setURL("www.tunisie-web.org "); 
    $crawler->addReceiveContentType("#text/html#"); 
   $crawler->addURLFilterRule("#\.(jpg|gif|png|pdf|jpeg|css|js)$# i"); 
    $crawler->setWorkingDirectory("C:/Users/mayss/Documents/travailcrawl/"); 
      $crawler->go(); 
    ?>
```

but it show me  the result below

0
1
Page requested: http://www.tunisie-web.org ()
Referer-page: 
3

and this error
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare parse_external_url() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\crawl\crawl.php:23) in C:\wamp\www\crawl\crawl.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you are re-declaring that function.

Probably You have included `C:\wamp\www\crawl\crawl.php` in which that function was declared  **OR** extended class `PHPCrawler.class.php` have same function.

**Solution:**

Rename the function, which declared in your `MyCrawler` class, like:

```
function parse_external_url( $url) {
  //======TO===========
function parse_external_url2( $url) {
  // OR to other name
```

---

**Note:** I suspect that you want to call function `parse_external_url` in your class rather then declaring, Coz declaring a function within another function is not a good practice. **If so,** call it properly; **If not,** then declare it with different name and outside the function `handleDocumentInfo` and call that function properly in `handleDocumentInfo` function of your class.